# exception trying to run first example in the Twisted book by McKellar & Fettig

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I was trying to tinker around with Twisted and see what it was all about. So I bought the book "Twisted", 2nd Edition, by Jessica McKellar & Abe Fettig, and downloaded and installed Python, Twisted, and zope.interface, and tried to type in and run their first example from page 12:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("Hello, Stupid!")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Server said: ", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def BuildProtocol(self, addr):
        return EchoClient()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection Failed."
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost."
        reactor.stop()

reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

There was a server portion too. I ran the server program, and then in another cmdline-window ran the client program (above). It yielded:

```
"Unhandled Error
Traceback..  (several lines - see attached screen-capture (oops - this won't let me attach images!)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-package\twisted\python\context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
---  ---
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 151, in _doReadOrWrite why = getattr(selectable, method)()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 593, in doConnect self._connectDone()
..
    exceptions.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
    Connection Failed.

Possible the problem would be more clear to me were I a Python expert, but I'm fairly new to it - having come from a C#, F#, C++ background.

What do you think could be causing this - has anyone else run into this problem? It's frustrating - I can't say this is an easy technology if I can't even get the first, totally-trivial example to run!

I'm using Windows 8 x64,  Python 2.7.5, Twisted 13.0.0 (the installer is Twisted-13.0.0.win-amd64-py2.7.msi), and I've added my python (C:\Python27) and Scripts to the PATH env-variable.

Comment: The "several lines" are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm shooting blind here, but I think the problem lies in a small typo - instead of `BuildProtocol`, it should read `buildProtocol`. The error appears when the `EchoFactory` instance tries to return new protocol instance - it returns `None` instead of `EchoClient` instance, and this `None` later is troublesome.

Comment: You da man, vonPetrushev!!  Thank you - you hit it on the head!  I had scrutinized the sample in the book repeatedly, and convinced myself there was no typo. But you're right - I did type that incorrectly. So, now I'm off into exploring this interesting library.